# Clearing chat pins results in a self-imposed moratorium on future actions

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, moderator-abilities

Eight steps to reproduce a trivial yet annoying bug whereby acting as a room owner/moderator you ban yourself from taking future action:

1. Create a new room in chat.

OR

1. Be a moderator and take your mod-hammer with you into chat.
2. Pin a chat message.
3. Unpin same.
4. Realize you didn't really want to unpin it; you were acting prematurely.
5. Try to pin said chat message again.
6. Get greeted by a notification bar saying:

   > You have already voted, but the voting has been cleared by a moderator
7. Repent of your fickle ways.
8. `goto 7`

Also note that you receive the same message even when you are a room owner but not a moderator, which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: You can only use your hammer once! Then it shatters into a million pieces.

Comment: That's not really a bug in behavior; the message just admittedly isn't quite optimal. The behavior is as intended.

Comment: Seeing as the dupe was removed, perhaps we should reopen this. And if this is status-bydesign, perhaps we could switch it to feature request instead, this behaviour is *really* annoying.

Comment: ...just post a new message with the same contents and pin it again? It shouldn't be a problem if the author of the message doesn't matter.

Comment: @badp can a moderator post a message as some other user?

Comment: Please add "8. See (7)"

Comment: @JanDvorak No, they can't.

Comment: @animuson Moderators can swing the hammer again, but backwards, so things that were shattered gets unshattered (?).

Comment: @Braiam No, even mods can't do this: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=10487533#10487533

Comment: Reproduced as room owner without mod powers, editing to reflect it.

Answer (score 6):

Another side effect of this that isn't mentioned in the question is that after 14 days (or however long a message is pinned, I forget atm) the message can't be repinned. You get the same error message.

This is terribly annoying, forcing you to create the message *all over again*, and that is usually less than optimal.

Can this be changed please?